# Search record by its related record

Tags: search

Can I search Contact record page with its related Account name?
I have Students records as Contacts and their affiliated Academic Programs as Accounts and I want to search Students by their Academic Programs. When I type Computer Science BS in search bar I should get all students affiliated to Computer Science BS. Is there any way to do this optimally?

Comment: Search only works on the records themselves, not on related records.  Without any customization, you have to use reports to do this.  You could build some automation to populate custom fields in the contact with the appropriate data from the account, then search could find the data in those new contact fields.

Comment: @DavidCheng Suppose I create a formula field on Contact which will be related Account name, can I index it and make it searchable?

Comment: search doesn't work on formula fields.  Vote on this idea:  https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bq79AAC